# How to change _POST index

Tags: php, html, arrays, post, input

I am creating a form with inputs type radio. I have retrieved the previous responses from the database and I put them in an array. And this is the result:

```
array(19) { ["1.1"]=> int(5) ["1.2"]=> int(2) ["1.3"]=> int(5) ["1.4"]=> int(2) ["1.5"]=> int(2) ["1.6"]=> int(4) ["1.7"]=> int(1) ["1.8"]=> int(3) ["1.9"]=> int(5) ["2.1"]=> int(5) ["2.2"]=> int(3) ["2.3"]=> int(1) ["2.4"]=> int(4) ["2.5"]=> int(2) ["3.1"]=> int(5) ["3.2"]=> int(5) ["3.3"]=> int(4) ["3.4"]=> int(3) ["4.1"]=> int(4) }
```

I have got here the question number 1.1 and the value 5. That its perfect, but when I send the form, new results by POST, are changing from 1.1 to 1_1 and so on like this:

```
array(19) { ["1_1"]=> string(1) "5" ["1_2"]=> string(1) "2" ["1_3"]=> string(1) "5" ["1_4"]=> string(1) "2" ["1_5"]=> string(1) "2" ["1_6"]=> string(1) "4" ["1_7"]=> string(1) "1" ["1_8"]=> string(1) "3" ["1_9"]=> string(1) "5" ["2_1"]=> string(1) "5" ["2_2"]=> string(1) "3" ["2_3"]=> string(1) "1" ["2_4"]=> string(1) "4" ["2_5"]=> string(1) "2" ["3_1"]=> string(1) "5" ["3_2"]=> string(1) "5" ["3_3"]=> string(1) "4" ["3_4"]=> string(1) "3" ["4_1"]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I am putting in the input, name="$variable", a variable that it gives me exactly the same 1.1, but I do not know what it's changing it it.

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $que_code; ?>" value="1"
```

In order to compare them I would like to change them back to 1.1, 1.2..and so on.

Comment: Please exhaustively search SO for your solution before posting your question, this will spare moderator time and reduce page bloat on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Add some "namespacing" - Instead of doing:

```
<input type="radio" name="1.1" value="1" />
```

Do:

```
<input type="radio" name="data[1.1]" value="1" />
```

...and you wont experience this problem :)

Comment: Thank very much I was trying -- <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $que_code; ?>[]" value="1" -- It was not working very well